# In Javascript are all built-in objects immutable?

Tags: javascript, object, immutability

I know that String and Number objects are immutable but are **all** built-in objects immutable as well?
If it's not true, can you give me an example of a built-in object that is mutable?

Comment: No, you can attach and delete properties to many of the built-in objects. Although, the prototypes of the constructor built-ins are non-configurable, non-enumerable, non-writable.

Comment: @MinusFour are you referring for example to String-objects? Can we change the properties of them?

Comment: That would be an instance of a String wrapped around an object, so that's not a built-in. Built-ins would be `Array`, `Object`, `Number`, `String` and their respective prototypes.

Comment: Wait, but so far as I know a String-object is for example var x = new String("John"). This is an immutable object because we can't modify anything of it. For example it's content, that's why we cannot make x.substr(1). That will not change the content of x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are mutable. Here are a list of mutable methods for arrays.

`push` - Elements are added on to the end of the array

`pop` - Elements are removed from the end of the array

`shift` - Elements are removed from the beginning of the array

`unshift` - Elements are added to the beginning of the array

`splice` - Adds/removes elements to an array

None of these methods create a new array, but modify the existing array.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, for instance an array is mutable. If you have an array of strings and you push a string to it, you don't get a new array with an extra string added to it. The original array is altered.